# Prestahop docker change execution_time

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, prestashop

I am testing Prestashop with their docker image useing docker-compose [Prestashop](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop)

I have 30 seconds of php max_execution_time and I don't see a way to change it so everytime I need to up the container already have 120 seconds of max_execution_time.

tried to change php.ini but every time I launch the container it resets to 30 seconds

How can I do it?

Comment: Got it, this worked for me:
I created my own php.ini and added it to my volumes .user.ini file on my docker-compose.override.yml

    volumes:
      - ./docker/override/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/.user.ini